# npm list firebase VS firebase --version

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I know both `npm list firebase` and `firebase --version` give you the version of firebase. However when I run

```
npm list firebase
`-- firebase@4.13.1
```

and when I run in the same directory

```
firebase --version
3.13.1
```

Why are these two versions not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're reporting about two completely different node modules.

`npm list firebase` shows the version of the npm module called "firebase" installed into the node project in the current directory.

`firebase --version` invokes the Firebase CLI to report its own version.  The Firebase CLI is normally installed globally from the npm module called "firebase-tools".